# java regex to get all matches between a String and the next pipe

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like that:

```
 ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
 ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS2|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
 ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
 ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
```

I need all the words between EC and the first |.

This does not work for me:

```
lAllText = lData.split("EC(.*?)|");
```

what I have to change do manage that issue?

Thanks for your help

Stefan

Comment: Pipe is a special character in regex. I guess you know now what to do. And why are you splitting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use look-behind and look-ahead groups to match your `Pattern`.

**Example**

```
// assuming multi-line, but not relevant
String input = 
    "ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS\n"
    + "ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS2|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS\n"
    + "ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS\n"
    + "ECLONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS|LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS";
    //                            | look behind for "EC"
    //                            |     | match any+ character reluctantly
    //                            |     |  | look ahead for "|" (escaped)
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=EC).+?(?=\\|)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

**Output**

```
LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS2
LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
LONG_TEXT_INSIDE_THIS
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below regex to get the value between EC and the first `|` symbol.

```
(?<=EC)[^\|]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yI3iS2/1)

Java regex would be,

```
"(?<=EC)[^\\|]*"
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=EC)` A lookbehind is used to set the matching marker just after to the string EC.
- `[^\|]*` Matches any character but not of `|` symbol zero or more times.

Comment: Explain your changes!

Answer (score 1):

To match all the tokens, you could do this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\G_?([^|_]+)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group(1));
}
```

matchList:

```
ECLONG
TEXT
INSIDE
THIS
```